# Why do you run other lines of codes of a python file(say test.py) when you are just importing a piece of test.py from somewhere else (say main.py)?

Tags: python

I have two python files. One is main.py which I execute. The other is test.py, from which I import a class in main.py.
Here is the sample code for main.py:

```
from test import Test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("You're inside main.py")
    test_object = Test()
```

And, here is the sample code for test.py:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print("you're initializing the class.")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('You executed test.py')
else:
    print('You executed main.py')
```

Finally, here's the output, when you execute main.py:

```
You executed main.py
You're inside main.py
you're initializing the class.
```

From the order of outputs above, you can see that once you import a piece of a file, the whole file gets executed immediately. I am wondering why? what's the logic behind that?
I am coming from java language, where all files included a single class with the same name. I am just confused that why python behaves this way.

Any explanation would be appricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is happening?

When you import the test-module, the interpreter runs through it, executing line by line. Since the `if __name__ == '__main__'` evaluates as false, it executes the else-clause. After this it continues beyond the `from test import Test` in main.py.

### Why does python execute the imported file?

Python is an interpreted language. Being interpreted means that the program being read and evaluated one line at the time. Going through the imported module, the interpreter needs to evaluate each line, as it has no way to discern which lines are useful to the module or not. For instance, a module could have variables that need to be initialized.

Python is designed to support multiple paradigms. This behavior is used in some of the paradigms python supports, such as procedural programming.

Execution allows the designer of that module to account for different use cases. The module could be imported or run as a script. To accommodate this, some functions, classes or methods may need to be redefined. As an example, a script could output non-critical errors to the terminal, while an imported module to a log-file.

### Why specify what to import?

Lets say you are importing two modules, both with a Test-class. If everything from those modules is imported, only one version of the Test-class can exist in our program. We can resolve this issue using different syntax.

```py
import package1
import package2

package1.Test()
packade2.Test()
```

Alternatively, you can rename them with the `as`-keyword.

```py
from package1 import Test
from package2 import Test as OtherTest

Test()
OtherTest()
```

Dumping everything into the global namepace (i.e `from test import *`) pollutes the namespace of your program with a lot of definitions you might not need and unintentionally overwrite/use.

Comment: alright, then why do you have to specify what pieces you want to import from the file? You say it goes through the whole file (which I don't deny, as we  can see from the output), so you have to have recognized all of them by the time you import it.

Comment: I am just confused with the logic.

Comment: Python most likely reads the full file since you may redefine your class or add class functions in your `else` clause, as it may have different usecases depending on if it's run as a module or the main program.

Comment: @AlbinSidås that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You have specify which pieces to import to avoid name-conflicts. For instance if you are importing two files, both with a Test-class. This can be resolved using regular `import package1`, `import package2`, and `package1.Test()` etc. Alternatively, you can rename them with `as`. Dumping everything into the global namepace (i.e `from test import *`) pollutes the namespace of your program with a lot of definitions you might not need and unintentionally overwrite/use.

Comment: Could you just wrap it all up in your reply? Please include your most recent comment as well as what @AlbinSidås suggested (he explains why it is important to read throught the whole file, however, still not clear about why python hast to execute through the whole file, it can just read through it looking for redefine of the class, but not to execute it all)

Comment: Updated the answer with the feedback:)

Answer (score 1):

> where all files included a single class with the same name

There is not such requirement imposed in `python`, you can put multiple classes, functions, values in single `.py` file for example

```
class OneClass:
    pass
class AnotherClass:
    pass
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
def diff(x,y):
    return x-y
pi = 22/7
```

is legal `python` file.

According to [interview with python's creator](https://www.artima.com/articles/the-making-of-python) modules mechanism in `python` was influenced by `Modula-2` and `Modula-3` languages. So maybe right question is why creators of said languages elected to implement modules that way?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, but it is not my concern. Somebody answered me (in comment section of another answer) above named Albin.